# Taxes for a foreign freelancer getting paid in the USA

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, self-employment, oregon

I, a Mexican citizen, was living in Portland last year and had a TN work visa, but decided to come back home. The company I was working for decided they wanted to keep working with me but as a freelancer. Since I already had a U.S. bank  account, I am getting paid there. I am given the form 1099 to file my taxes.

- Do you know what percentage of what I am earning needs to be paid to the IRS?
- Am I allowed to do this, even if I'm not living in PDX anymore?

Not sure if my Social Security Number is still valid if I'm no longer a resident.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not that you are a remote foreign freelancer now, but that you actually lived in the U.S. in 2017.

Your income tax is for that period. If more was withheld then you are due a refund.

The IRS has rules for determining if you were a resident, part-time resident, or a non-resident for tax purposes, depending on how long you stayed. These rules are explained in the instructions booklets that come with the tax forms and here:

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/determining-alien-tax-status

As to the current situation (remote work by a foreign national who is not a permanent resident), I don't believe you should be taxed by the U.S.:

https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/3555456-i-work-remotely-for-a-company-in-another-state-from-whom-i-received-a-1099-misc-do-i-pay-taxes-to-that-state-or-just-to-the-state-i-m-living-in